# Non-trivial $P^1$ bundle over complex tori

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles

I am studying holomorphic $\mathbb P^1$-bundle over complex tori $\mathbb C^2/\Lambda$. There should be many non-trivial examples, but I can't write one explicitly. So I wonder if there are any canonical good examples of non-trivial bundles?

Comment: Can you construct a non-trivial rank 2 holomorphic vector bundle on your tori?

Comment: By non-trivial do you mean "not isomorphic to $(\mathbb C^2/\Lambda)\times \mathbb P^1$", or "not arising as the fiberwise quotient of a rank two vector bundle"? I assume the former, in which case you just need a rank two bundle $E$ that is either (a) non-split, or (b) splits as $E \cong L\oplus M$ with $L\not\cong M$. So in fact it suffices to set $L = \mathcal O$ and find a single non-trivial line bundle $M$; can you do this?

Comment: I think you can construct these by picking a nontrivial automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb P^1$ and letting every generator $\lambda$ of $\Lambda$ act on $\mathbb P^1$ by $\lambda \cdot x = f(x)$. Then $\Lambda$ acts on $\mathbb C^n \times \mathbb P^1$ by $\lambda \cdot (z, x) = (z + \lambda, f(x))$, and the quotient is a holomorphic fiber bundle over your torus. It should be nontrivial as well because looping around a path that represents a generator on the torus acts by $f$ upstairs.